# How to solve django.db.utils.DataError: (1406, "Data too long for column 'product_team' at row 1")

Tags: mysql, django, mysql-python

After running a function containing the below create process :

```
client_daily.objects.create(client_id=c,title=c.title,products=product_list,categories=categories[:-2],product_team=product_team[:-2],pcategory=pcategory[:-2],date=date)
```

I came up with the error:

Traceback:

```
File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
  112.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
  209.         res = self._query(query)

File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in _query
  315.         db.query(q)

File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py" in query
  239.         _mysql.connection.query(self, query)

The above exception ((1406, "Data too long for column 'product_team' at row 1")) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/intranet/views.py" in cron_job_functions
  2103.         message=my_scheduled_job()

File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/intranet/views.py" in my_scheduled_job
  882.             client_daily.objects.create(client_id=c,title=c.title,products=product_list,categories=categories[:-2],product_team=product_team[:-2],pcategory=pcategory[:-2],date=date)

File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  85.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in create
  399.         obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)

File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  796.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  824.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  908.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  947.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  85.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  1045.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1054.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  94.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/six.py" in reraise
  685.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)

File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
  112.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
  209.         res = self._query(query)

File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in _query
  315.         db.query(q)

File "/www/wwwroot/geolocator/geolocator_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py" in query
  239.         _mysql.connection.query(self, query)

Exception Type: DataError at /cron_job_functions/
Exception Value: (1406, "Data too long for column 'product_team' at row 1")
```

Here is my model :

```
class client_daily(models.Model):
    client_id = models.ForeignKey(client_coordinates, null=True, blank=True,related_name='customers', verbose_name=u'πελάτες',on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    products = models.CharField(max_length=4000, blank=True, null=True)
    categories = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True,db_index=True)
    product_team = models.CharField(max_length=350, blank=True, null=True,db_index=True)
    pcategory = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True,db_index=True)
    date = models.DateField(db_index=True)
```

I try to fix the issue by doing `python manage.py migrate --fake` but it keeps complaining.

How can i fix this?

Comment: change `product_team` to `TextField` ie `product_team = models.TextField(blank=True, db_index=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, CharField supports a max_length of 256 chars only for most database backends (You can check your database backend to find that value) . The value you are trying to pass in product_team was more than 256 chars. That's why you are getting the error. Change your product_team to TextField which does not any such limit.

You will face the same problem with your products field as well. So I would suggest you change that as well